# How to cover Akka.Net actors SupervisorStrategy by unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, akka, akka.net

Is it possible to test that my actor uses specific `SupervisionStrategy`? E.g. I want to be sure that after child actor throws an exception, it will be stopped and parent actor will receive `Terminated` message.

I tried to make it in this way:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class SupervisionStrategyTest : TestKit
{
    public SupervisionStrategyTest() : base(@"akka.suppress-json-serializer-warning=true")
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var parent = Sys.ActorOf(Props.Create<ParentActor>());
        var testProbe = CreateTestProbe("subscriber");

        parent.Tell(testProbe);

        parent.Tell(new object());

        var t = testProbe.ExpectMsg<ChildActor.Terminated>(10.Seconds());
    }
    public class ParentActor : ReceiveActor
    {
        private TestProbe parent;

        public ParentActor()
        {
            var child = Context.ActorOf<ChildActor>();

            Receive<TestProbe>(
                m =>
                {
                    parent = m;
                });

            // when child actor stopped we should receive this, but we don't
            Receive<Terminated>(
                m =>
                {
                    parent.Tell(new ChildActor.Terminated());
                });

            ReceiveAny(
                m =>
                {
                    child.Tell(new object());
                });
        }

        protected override SupervisorStrategy SupervisorStrategy()
        {
            return new OneForOneStrategy(
                maxNrOfRetries: 0, // no restarts 
                withinTimeRange: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                localOnlyDecider: x => Directive.Stop);
        }
    }

    public class ChildActor : UntypedActor
    {
        protected override void OnReceive(object message)
        {
            throw new Exception("Test");
        }

        public class Terminated
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it not works. Seems like `Parent` can't get the `Terminated` message from akka system. Is it a bug in TestKit or I missed something?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly watch over child actor (`Context.Watch(Context.ActorOf<ChildActor>())`)?

Comment: @Horusiath, well, in that case I will test the fact that actor was terminated, not logic placed within ``Terminated`` message handler